# Manage multiple form validation in PageView flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have multiple forms inside a PageView, Forms are in different files like registration_form.dart contains the Sign-Up form and so on. In my App, each page contains a different Form. I want that when the user clicks on "Continue", the form will be validated and in an error situation, the user will be warned. I call all the pages in one class called Body as shown below. The "Continue" button is inside of it in the Opacity container. If there is a better approach to follow as a solution I am open to recommendations.

```
      @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.65,
              child: Flex(
                direction: Axis.horizontal,
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                    child: PageView(
                      controller: _controller,
                      //physics: new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      children: [
                        RegisterForm(),
                        WelcomeForm(),
                        //CompanyForm(),
                        //CompanyNextForm(),
                        //CompanyLogoForm(),
                        //FinancingDataForm(),
                        //UtilityForm(),
                        //MatrixInformationForm(),
                        //MatrixInformationNextForm(),
                        //MatrixInformationLastForm(),
                        //PriceBuildingForm(),
                        //InstallKitForm(),
                        //InstallKitDetailedForm(),
                        //CustomPricingForm(),
                        //CustomPricingNextForm(),
                        //FillRow1Form(),
                        //FillItem1Row1Form(),
                        //FillItem2Row1Form(),
                        //FillItem3Row1Form(),
                        //FillRow2Form(),
                        //FillItem1Row2Form(),
                        //FillItem2Row2Form(),
                        //FillItem3Row2Form(),
                        //FillRow3Form(),
                        //FillItem1Row3Form(),
                        //FillItem2Row3Form(),
                        //FillItem3Row3Form(),
                        //InvoicingForm(),
                        //FinancingForm(),
                        //FinancingNextForm(),
                        //FinancingLastForm(),
                        //FinalizeForm(),
                        //DoneForm(),
                        //BookingForm(),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: ResponsiveLayout.isSmallScreen(context)
                  ? 10
                  : ResponsiveLayout.isMediumScreen(context)
                      ? 10
                      : 10,
            ),
            Opacity(
              opacity: 1, //currentIndex == 20 ? 0 : 1,
              child: Container(
                  height: 50,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(16, 88, 198, 1),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                  ),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      _controller.nextPage(
                          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                          curve: Curves.easeIn);
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      height: 100,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(16, 88, 198, 1),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                              height: 100.0,
                              child: Center(
                                child: RichText(
                                  text: TextSpan(children: [
                                    WidgetSpan(
                                        child: Text(
                                      'Continue  ',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: ResponsiveLayout
                                                .isSmallScreen(context)
                                            ? 12
                                            : ResponsiveLayout.isMediumScreen(
                                                    context)
                                                ? 12
                                                : 15,
                                      ),
                                    )),
                                    WidgetSpan(
                                      child: Icon(
                                        Icons.arrow_forward,
                                        size: ResponsiveLayout.isSmallScreen(
                                                context)
                                            ? 12
                                            : ResponsiveLayout.isMediumScreen(
                                                    context)
                                                ? 12
                                                : 15,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ]),
                                ),
                              )),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: so, no one found any solution for this? XD

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I was struggling with the same question recently and was looking for a good approach. Maybe this answer will be helpful for any other developer looking for the answer.

### Approach

Currently, in my case, I used **form keys** for validations and function callbacks. This solution did the job for me because I needed to take input as raw text. Others like multiple choice options similar where there were predefined outputs.

To describe my solution more explicitly. Consider this example, we want to get basic details of the user like name, age, city etc. For user input like the name, we can use `TextFormField`. This will give access to the `onChanged` callback for validation. To access the response in the `PageView` widget containing the class. You can use the `TextEditingController`.

Now, we can then simply add the `Form` widget at the parent of the basic form widget `build` method.

Finally for multiple choice questions. We can provide a callback function like `onTap` to the widget of `PageView`. This function will be called whenever the user interacts with the dropdown or similar widget.

> **Note**: If we have multiple forms in the `PageView` widget. You will be needing separate form keys for individual forms.

### Code Example

So, we have the main **form_screen.dart** containing the `PageView` widget and **basic_profile.dart** containing our form. Both the files should look something like this:

**form_screen.dart**

```dart
...
// define the variables and keys here
final _basicProfileKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
final _userName = TextEditingController();
late String _userGender;

...

// callback function that we will be passing to the BasicProfile
// widget on the other page
void _userGender(String value) {
 _userGender = value;
}

...

// the submission callback that will be called whenever the user
// clicks on the next or save button available in the class file
// (this file) containing the PageView widget
void _submissionCallback(){
  if(_pageViewIndex == 0) {
  final validationStatus = _basicProfileKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false;

    if(validationStatus) {
      // implement your logic here and then move to next page in the pageview
    }
  }
}


...

// Build method widget tree containing the PageView and BasicProfile
// widgets
child: PageView(
  children: [
    BasicProfile(
      basicProfileKey: _basicProfileKey,
      userName: _userName,
      userGenderCallback: userGender
      ),
  ]
),
```

**basic_profile.dart**

```
...

// declare the variables for this widget which we will be initialised
// via constructor 
final GlobalKey<FormState> basicProfileKey;
final TextEditingController userName;
final Function(String) userGenderCallback;

...

@override
void initState(){
// initialise the default values here if any and call the
// callback function received above
userGenderCallback(_defaultValue);
}

...

Widget build(BuildContext context){
  ...
  child: Form(
    key: basicProfileKey,
  ...
    TextFieldForm(
      onValidate: (){
      // do the validation here
      }
    )
  ...
    DropDown(
      onChanged: (value) {
      // logic for validation
      userGenderCallback(value);
      }
    )

}
```

In my approach used `setState` as the state management solution but [other state solutions](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) can also be used for easier state sharing between the widgets.

Hope this helps!